# How to open outlook compose mail from sharepoint 2010 progamaticallly

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, outlook, office-interop

i need to open outlook compaose mail from sharepoint programatically ,i tried this code but it only open outlook process but the compose mail window didn't appear

```
  using (SPSite currentSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID))
            {
                using (SPWeb currentWeb = currentSite.OpenWeb(SPContext.Current.Web.ID))
                {
                    WebURL = currentWeb.Url;
                    currentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    SPList correspondences = currentWeb.Lists.TryGetList("list1");

                    SPListItem correspondenceItem = correspondences.GetItemById(id);
                    WebURL = currentWeb.Url;
                    SPAttachmentCollection CorrespondenceAttachemt = correspondenceItem.Attachments;

                                           Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem oMailItem = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

                    oMailItem.Body = body;
                    oMailItem.Subject = title;



                    oMailItem.Display();

                }
            }
```

Comment: you might be getting an exception on `oMailItem.Display();`. Try attaching breakpoints on your code

Comment: yes...the error is   "Microsoft Exchange is not available.  Either there are network problems or the Exchange server is down for maintenance."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is running on the SharePoint server, right? In that case you will start Outlook on the server side, not client. More than that, Outlook (just like any other Office app) cannot be used in a service.

Why not use the mailto url?

Comment: i didn't use mailto url because i want to add attachments in this compose mail from an item in sharepoint list,also i want to fill subject

Comment: it's seem to be issue in configration in sharepoint because i tried this code in console application it open outlook compose mail

Comment: use "mailto:email address" to open Outlook Compose Email. it wont depend on the configuration of sharepoint, its simple Javascript.

Comment: @SaghirA.Khatri , i want to update sharepoint list item in my code and  in the same block of code i want to open outlook compose contains attachments and data that exist in this sharepoint list item

Comment: If you want to show the window on the client side, then your code must also run in the client side, not on the server.

Comment: How do I add an attachment with the mailto url?

Comment: You can't. mailto can only set recipients, subject, and body.

Answer (score 0):

By default oMailItem.Display is False. Change it to true.

```
 oMailItem.Display ( true );
```

this should work now.

Comment: is it worked with you? ,i have tried it but still not working,the OUTLOOK process is already opened in task manager but the outlook compose mail window is not, note that i tried my code in console app and it worked fine

Comment: did u added `true` argument in `Display()` Method??

Comment: i get this error "Microsoft Exchange is not available.  Either there are network problems or the Exchange server is down for maintenance."

Comment: i guess you have problem with your outlook.